# Remove CouchDB admin user

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I accidentaly added admin user in Couch DB and I cant remember password for it. I tried to reinstal CouchDB in local, but admin is still there. Im on mac book.

Is there any way to remove this user?

Answer (score 0):

For server-admins, they are added to your database's `local.ini` configuration file. Thus, they are accessible via the `_config` API endpoints:

```
GET /_config/admins

{
  "admin": "<<hashed-password>>"
}
```

As a result, they can *also* be deleted via HTTP. (if you're logged in)

```
DELETE /_config/admins/admin

{
  "ok": true
}
```

Since you specifically mentioned that you forgot the password, you can manually delete the entry in your `/etc/couchdb/local.ini` file, it'll be listed like:

```
[admins]
admin=<<hashed-password>>
```

Simply delete the line starting with `admin=` and restart your server.

See the [docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/intro/security.html) for more information